# Why does my Async custom validator in Angular app works with typed input but not with pasted input?

Tags: angular, validation

I have created a custom validator that checks whether an email already exists in MySQL database. It works in that when a user types in an email that already exists in a database, an appropriate warning message will appear and not allow the admin to insert an existing user.

However, after testing it a few times, it looks like this validation can be easily broken by simply copying the email address from the database and pasting it in the form field. It is worth to note that when pasting in the email the first time round, it doesnt validate the email but when I then delete it and paste it in the second time, it then recognises it.  I have shown the process in the attached photos below:

[image: First input]

[image: Second input]
Please also see my code:

My custom validator:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncValidator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PatientsService } from './patients.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export function uniqueUsernameValidator(patientService: PatientsService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return patientService.checkUserEmail(c.value).pipe(
            map(users => {
                return users && users.length > 0 ? { 'uniqueUsername': true } : null;
            })
        );
    };
}




@Directive({
    selector: '[uniqueUsername]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UniqueUsernameValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class UniqueUsernameValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {

    constructor(private patientService: PatientsService) { }

    validate(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return uniqueUsernameValidator(this.patientService)(c);
    }

}
```

component I am using it in:

```
email: [
        null,
        [Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(30),Validators.email],
        [this.usernameService.usernameValidator()]
      ]
```

Referenced in my html

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">

    <label for="inputemail"id="label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" formControlName="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4"placeholder="Email">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="addForm.get('email').hasError('maxlength') && addForm.get('email').touched">
        Please enter maximum 30 characters.
       </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="addForm.get('email').hasError('required') && addForm.get('email').touched">
        Please enter an email address.
       </div>
       <div class="alert alert-danger"*ngIf="addForm.get('email').hasError('email') &&  addForm.get('email').touched">
        Please insert a valid email address.
      </div>

      <!--If same email exists...-->
      <div class="alert alert-danger"*ngIf=" addForm.controls['email']?.errors?.emailExists">
        Email already exists
      </div>
  </div>
```

Could someone please advise ? I am trying for it to also validate clipboard events (copy and paste) the first time round.

Comment: Do you know which DOM events the validator is being invoked for?

Comment: The aim is for the validator to work upon user's entry in the form,not upon submission. Apologies as I am quite new to Angular so not 100% sure if I'm understanding you correctly

Comment: What I meant was that if the validator is only being invoked for (for example) key-presses but not paste operations invoked from the mouse then that's one possible explanation. You need to find out what human-user events will trigger your validation code, and then alter Angular's validator configuration to make it fire for clipboard events.

Comment: Ahh yes it only fires for key presses as it currently exists.  However I would like it to fire for clipboard events (copy and paste) as well. Do you know how I would go about editing my code to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: I don't see where you use `[uniqueUsername]` selector in your template

Comment: Apologies as I can't put it in stackblitz as it is all done though an API.  I don't seem to need to use the selector as the validator does fire and functions ok. The issue is that it only fires when individual types text but doesnt fire when the same text is pasted via clipboard instead.

Comment: Reactive Forms are a better candidate for these kinds of forms. Reactive forms are more fine grained and simpler in such cases.

Comment: you are writing template driven and want the behavior of reactive. Is there any specific reason to use template driven forms instead of reactive forms ?

Comment: Angular does not trigger async validators unless all sync validators pass validation (for performance reasons). So the reason can be that value pasted, is not a valid email or exceeds 30 characters?

Comment: your question is full of missprints and irrelevant code, so kinda must to downvote it. There is no issues with paste/text drop and angular validators -- all ways work. When making stackblitz you change http requests to some dummy methods e.g. timeout https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-m1gey4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this :

```js
onPasteEmail(): void {
  addForm.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

```html
<input (paste)="onPasteEmail()">
```

paste event will be trigger when you copy&paste your email the first time, then updateValueAndValidity() function from reactive form will trigger your validation

Answer (score 0):

Use ReactiveForms instead, there's no reason to make it more complex than needed.
Hardcoded fixes for the 'onPaste' is sort of ridiculous to rely on.